# Modsecurity cookie match

Tags: mod-security, cookies, cpanel

I run a small webhosting service (`CPanel` + `ModSecurity`) and I personnaly host few `laravel` projects on it. I noticed that when I (or anyone) visit multiple pages quickly (one after the other), at some point I get a `Too Many Redirects` error after the 6th or 7th visit (Redirected to `/`)

After few research, I noticed that it's due to a `ModSecurity` match on a cookie, and when it matches, the matched session is locked in this redirection loop until cookies are manually cleared (for that domain). Here is an extract of the `ModSecurity` logs showing the match and the response ([Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/FmYZKhN7)).

I don't get why it's matching "sometimes" (always when logged-in as a user), and how to prevent it. If you guys have an idea...

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

This is a known false alert for this rule: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/issues/244

You can fix this by adding the following to your config after the config that loads that rule (`/usr/local/apache/conf/modsec_vendor_configs/
OWASP/rules/REQUEST-41-APPLICATION-ATTACK-XSS.conf`):

```
 SecRuleUpdateTargetById 973337 !REQUEST_COOKIES:oph_session
```

Note also that in the latest version of the CRS, this rule is has changed to 941120. You appear to be using an old pre-release version of the 3.0.0 CRS.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. These rules seems to be bundled with ModSecurity shipped with Cpanel. I will redirect the support here, and check if I can update them